# datetimepickerでAM/PM表記から24時間表記に変更できない。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

rails で bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails の gemを導入し、
カレンダーの入力機能を実装しております。

デフォルトだと、AM・PMで入力時間が表示されるため、
24時間のフォーマットに変更しようと思っております。

調べていると以下のようにするとできるみたいなのですが、上手く行きませんでした。

$('#datetimepicker_05').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'});

他にもこういうのとか、手当たり次第に試したのですが、ダメでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974697/datetimepicker-am-pm-dropdown

原因がわからないのですが、どなたか、心当たりのある方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

ブラウザのjavascriptコンソールにはエラーが表示されず、AM/PM表記であれば問題なく表示されます。

Comment: 上手くいかない、というのがformatを指定しない場合と同じ動きをするということなら、`YYYY/MM/DD` を除いてみると日付選択は消えるでしょうか？また、初期化時に設定する代わりに [`$(...).data('DateTimePicker').format(...)`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#format) とするとどうでしょうか？

Comment: bootstrap3-datetimepicker-railsのサンプルをベースに試したところ、format指定がdata属性で行われていたのでこれを変更すると24時間表記にできました。 https://github.com/unarist/bs3dp-test/commit/a55184e

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
「format指定がdata属性で行われていたのでこれを変更すると‌​24時間表記にできました。」←こちらを試しますと、上手く行きました。本当にありがとうございます。javascriptの方ばかりを見ておりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formatの形式に問題はないと思うので、以下のような点が考えられます。今回の場合は後者だったようですね。

- 既に初期化されている場合、二回目の初期化はオプション含め無視されます

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/v4.14.30/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/v4.14.30/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
```

- `<input>` 要素のdata属性でformatを指定していると、初期化時のformatは無視されます

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/v4.14.30/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/v4.14.30/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: 「format指定がdata属性で行われていたのでこれを変更すると‌​24時間表記にできました。」

←こちらにて解決しました。また、解決策と異なる回答にチェックマークをつけてしまいましたため、チェックマークを更新しました。非礼をお許しください。

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-datetimepickerが使っている[momentのリファレンス](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)によりますと`HH`か`H`で24時間表示になります。(`HH`だと午前3時が03:00になりますが、`H`だと3:00になります)

`HH`はもうすでに試したようですので、原因は`$('#datetimepicker_05').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'});`の呼びがが早すぎるのではないかと思います。以下のように`document.ready`で呼び出すと、ちゃんと表示されるはずです。

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker_05').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'});
});
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
document.readyで呼び出す方法でも試してみました。
しかし、ダメでした。
また、試しに sideBySide: true や showTodayButton: true をすると、上手くいきました。 そのため、余計に理由がわかりません・・・。

Comment: 別の方からの回答で解決しました。
「format指定がdata属性で行われていたのでこれを変更すると‌​24時間表記にできました。」←こちらを試しますと、上手く行きましたjavascriptの方ばかりを見ておりview側は失念しておりました・・・。

Answer (score 0):

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('ja');
  $('.some_class').datetimepicker({
        i18n:{
      ja:{
       months:[
        '1月','2月','3月','4月',
        '5月','6月','7月','8月',
        '9月','10月','11月','12月',
       ],
       dayOfWeek:[
        "日", "月", "火", "水",
        "木", "金", "土",
       ]
      }
     },
      format: 'Y-m-d H:i',///   hを大文字に変更すればOKでした!
      timepicker:true,
      lang:'ja'
  }
    );
```

---

```
(function( $ ){
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('ja');
  $('.some_class').datetimepicker({
        i18n:{
      ja:{
       months:[
        '1月','2月','3月','4月',
        '5月','6月','7月','8月',
        '9月','10月','11月','12月',
       ],
       dayOfWeek:[
        "日", "月", "火", "水",
        "木", "金", "土",
       ]
      }
     },
      format: 'Y-m-d h:i',
      timepicker:false,
      lang:'ja',
      use24hours: true, << 24時間
   }
  );
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score -1):

こちらではどうですか？

```
$('#datetimepicker_05').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y/m/d H:i'
});
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試したのですが、結果はダメでした。railsで実装しているのですが、何か他のgemなり、javascriptが干渉しているのでしょうか？少なくともjavascriptコンソールにはエラーが出ていないので、よくわからないですが・・・・。

Comment: 別の方からの回答で解決しました。 「format指定がdata属性で行われていたのでこれを変更すると‌​24時間表記にできました。」←こちらを試しますと、上手く行きましたjavascriptの方‌​ばかりを見ておりview側は失念しておりました・・・。

Answer (score -1):

formatで「H」は12時間のフォーマットになっています。
24時間のフォーマットを使いたい場合は「h」と書きます、例えば

```
$('#datetimepicker_05').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm'});
```